# Bidirectionnal protocol working when changing networking

Tags: networking, websocket, protocols, ip-address

I would like a bidirectional protocol working between two computer to send data between each other that will continuous to work when i change network (in java).

I tried to use websocket to send data between the two computer (not that the two computer are client and server the server is in amazon with a static ip address,while the client is in my local network) i this is the behaviour observed.

1. When i try to connect the client to the server the communication works and data are sent very well between each other.
2. But when i switch the client from one network to another network.

but when i switch my client from one network to another network (because the network lost internet connection),obviously the client has changed ip address, the communication between the computers (client are server) doesn't work any more. How can i do such that this communication still available?

If it isn't possible, is there any bidirectionnal protocol that  still working when i switch the client from one network to another one?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think to another bidirectional protocol that automatically handles ip switch. I just can guarantee there is no "standard" protocol that does it.

It is something that you can handle at application level on top on WebSocket.

For example:

- server side: you assign an univocal id to every client. You keep track of connected clients and stop tracking them when they are disconnected for too long time. If a client with a known id asks to start a websocket connection you can continue from where you left off, else you assign a new id;
- client side: when the connection goes down (I suppose onerror event) you periodically try to start a new websocket handshake sending your id;

of course using a simple id is not so secure and it does not take into account if you reload the page or open it from another tab. Anyway those problem can be easily solved in lot of different ways (for example if the user are authenticated).